# If each uncountable set $T$ has a countable subset, can we form $T$ by a union of countable subsets?

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

I was working my way through the set theory chapter in my Analysis textbook when I stumbled across these two theorems:

> 1. Every infinite set has a countable subset
> 2. A union of countable subsets is countable

My question is: Given an uncountable set $T$, can we partition it into a collection of countable subsets $C_1, C_2, ..., C_n$ such that $$\bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i = T$$
implying that $T$ is countable by Theorem 2?

Now, obviously, the answer is no. But why?

Comment: Since $T$ is uncountable, this means by definition that $\# T>\aleph_0$. But since the union is disjoint, $\# \bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i =\sum_{i=1}^n \# C_i=n\aleph_0=\aleph_0$. But of course $\aleph_0>\aleph_0$ is contradictory. One can prove that the finite union of countable sets is countable with no AOC, but probably someone will comment that countable union of sets countable or that every infinite set has a countable subset are AOC-dependent.

Comment: Sorry, what does # mean?

Comment: Cardinality. ${}{}{}$

Comment: From where do you establish that $|C_i| = \aleph_0$

Comment: Statement 2 must be adjusted to: A *countable* union of countable sets is countable. If arbitrary unions are allowed, *any* set $X$ is the union of the collection of its singletons $\{x\},$ and each set of this union is countable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, we can always partition an infinite set to countable subsets. But the partition itself is not going to be finite, and certainly not countable. Namely, if $T$ is uncountable, and $T=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ where each $A_i$ is countable, then $I$ is necessarily uncountable. In fact we can prove that $|I|=|T|$.

Similarly, you can partition every set into singletons. Doesn't mean that every set is finite.

(I won't get into issues of the axiom of choice here, but let me point out that it is needed for both statements to hold.)